# Fetching the data from sql join using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the data from my join query.
But after running it. It says that undefined index. Please explain to me what's wrong like I'm a potato. Thanks :)

```
$join_query = "select customer.customer_email, item.ItemId, item.ItemPrice, cart.qty 
        from customer, item, cart
        where customer.customer_email = '" . $_SESSION['customer_email'] . "' AND item.ItemId = cart.orderId";

$run_join = mysqli_query($con, $join_query);

while($row_boat = mysqli_fetch_array($run_join)){

    $sales_email = $_SESSION['customer_email'];
    $sales_itemid = $row_boat['item.ItemId'];
    $sales_itemprice = $row_boat['item.ItemPrice'];
    $sales_qty = $row_boat['cart.qty'];
    $sales_total = $sales_itemprice * $sales_qty;
    //$sales_date =
    $insert_sales = "insert into sales (customer_email, ItemId, ItemPrice, Quantity, Total)
            values ('$sales_email', $'sales_itemid', '$sales_itemprice', '$sales_qty', '$sales_total')";

    $run_sales = mysqli_query($con, $insert_sales);
```

Comment: Paste your full error message!!!

Comment: Remove the table aliases when calling the record: ie: change `$row_boat['item.ItemPrice'];` to `$row_boat['ItemPrice'];`

Comment: Plus typo here `$'sales_itemid',`

Comment: @RamRaider Thank you! :D

Comment: @Saty Thanks for pointing that out ! The potato is now happy <3

Comment: No problems Mr. Potato '-)

Answer (score -1):

```
while($row_boat = mysqli_fetch_array($run_join, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
```

This should fix your error